# Change ip address format

Tags: bash

Someone can help me to write a bash script that change ip address from the folowing format

```
192.168.1.0/27
```

to this format, that write mask beside the ip

```
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.224
```

i Need that script it and calculate it, to change 27 to 224, and if slash is 24 will write 255.255.255.0 etc...

Comment: `echo "192.168.1.0 255.255.255.224"` Job Done. What? Not what you wanted? Perhaps you should make a clearer question.

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you have python 3.X (3.4 in my case):

```
python3.4 -c "import ipaddress; print(ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/27').with_netmask)"
```

Output:

> 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.224

Comment: thansk for ur anser, but i need bash script

Comment: Bash is usually "glue" for other executables. Do you not have python?

Comment: no, i didnt study python, and my task to do it on bash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer this question:

```
IP="127.0.0.1/27"
REM=`echo "$IP" | sed 's/^.*\/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/'`
IP=`echo "$IP" | sed 's/\(^.*\)\/[0-9][0-9]/\1/'`

REM=`echo "$REM - 24" | bc`

MASKTAIL=0

while [[ "$REM" > 0 ]]
do
     MASKTAIL=`echo "$MASKTAIL + 2^(8-$REM)" | bc`
     REM=`echo "$REM - 1" | bc`
done

echo "$IP 255.255.255.$MASKTAIL"
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnet_and_host_counts for Prefix-Mask description

Pd.: Doesn't work on values < 24 or > 31